# Quiz not declared and maybe inaccessible

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

Not Sure Why Im getting Quiz not declared error?(see bold **Quiz**)  Can I get some help with this please. Ive tried to declare Quiz several different ways but Im stuck.  This Quiz is going to be modified more in the Questions and answers part as I want to use this template as a bible study tool.  Thanks for your help.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form2
Dim TestAboutMe As New Quiz3x
Friend WithEvents QuizStart, AnswerSubmit As New System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3, RadioButton4 As New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
Friend WithEvents Label1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Label

Sub ResetQuiz()
    TestAboutMe.Clear()
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 1 ?", {"2", "3", "5", "7"}.ToList, "2"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 2 ?", {"3", "5", "4", "7"}.ToList, "4"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 3 ?", {"6", "99", "7", "1"}.ToList, "6"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 4 ?", {"8", "0", "9", "2"}.ToList, "8"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 5 ?", {"12", "10", "5", "7"}.ToList, "10"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 6 ?", {"6", "66", "666", "12"}.ToList, "12"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 7 ?", {"13", "15", "14", "55"}.ToList, "14"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 8 ?", {"15", "14", "17", "16"}.ToList, "16"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 9 ?", {"17", "18", "12", "33"}.ToList, "18"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 10 ?", {"20", "18", "19", "22"}.ToList, "20"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 11 ?", {"23", "24", "22", "32"}.ToList, "22"))
    TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question("What is 2 x 12 ?", {"23", "24", "25", "12"}.ToList, "24"))
    RadioButton1.Checked = False : RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False : RadioButton4.Checked = False
    RadioButton1.Visible = True : RadioButton2.Visible = True
    RadioButton3.Visible = True : RadioButton4.Visible = True
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Quiz3x
Private Property _Questions As New List(Of Question)
Private Index As Integer = 0
Private _CurrentQuestion As Question
Private Property _CorrectAnswers As Integer = 0
Private Property _TestComplete As Boolean = False
Public ReadOnly Property TestComplete As Boolean
    Get
        Return _TestComplete
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property CurrentQuestion As Question
    Get
        Return _CurrentQuestion
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property TotalQuestions As Integer
    Get
        Return _Questions.Count
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property CorrectAnswers As Integer
    Get
        Return _CorrectAnswers
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Questions As List(Of Question)
    Get
        Return _Questions
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub NextQuestion()
    Dim TmpIndex As Integer = Index
    Index = Index + 1
    If TmpIndex > Questions.Count - 1 Then
        _TestComplete = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    _CurrentQuestion = Questions(TmpIndex)
End Sub
Public Sub AddQuestion(ByVal Question As Question)
    _Questions.Add(Question)
End Sub
Public Sub GradeQuestion(ChosenAnswer As String)
    If ChosenAnswer = CurrentQuestion.CorrectAnswer Then
        _CorrectAnswers = _CorrectAnswers + 1
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Clear()
    _Questions.Clear()
    Index = 0
    _CorrectAnswers = 0
    _TestComplete = False
End Sub
Class Question
    Private _Question As String
    Private _Choices As New List(Of String)
    Private _CorrectAnswer As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Question As String
        Get
            Return _Question
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Choices As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _Choices
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property CorrectAnswer As String
        Get
            Return _CorrectAnswer
        End Get
    End Property
    Sub New(Question As String, Choices As List(Of String), CorrectAnswer As String)
        _Question = Question
        _Choices = Choices
        _CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer
    End Sub
End Class
End Class
```

This is form 2
Form 1 has a button that is a msgbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sub ResetQuiz() change every

```
TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question(...
```

to

```
TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(New Quiz.Question(...
```

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE:
TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(Quiz.Question(........
to

TestAboutMe.AddQuestion(New Quiz3x.Question(.................